# Oracle incorrect values when using DBMS_CRYPTO to decrypt a CLOB

Tags: oracle, function, encryption, procedure, clob

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a CLOB. I have a test CASE below, which utilizes functions to accomplish this task and was taken from the following link.

[Error while using DBMS_CRYPTO function to decrypt CLOB data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135899/error-while-using-dbms-crypto-function-to-decrypt-clob-data)

Once the anonymous block creates the encrypted CLOB I am using an update statement, which calls a decrypt function to ensure it matches the original string.

I've tried initializing the CLOB before encryption with a call to empty_clob() but I can't seem to get this test CASE to decrypt the CLOB and return back the original value,  which I started with.

The string being generated to encrypt is small but the test CASE is a little lengthy so I can provide a step by step guide on what I'm doing.

The last step in the test is a dump() of the decrypted CLOB, which shows some unusual characters in the middle of the CLOB that weren't in the input.

While looking at the documentation I did see an example using RANDOMBYTES on a string bur that will not work for me as it would be very unlikely I will get the same random bytes for the encryption and decryption.

I'm testing this in livesql  for those who want to emulate my testing environment.

I was hoping someone could tell me where the problem is and provide the necessary fixes I need to get this functioning properly.

Thanks in advance to all who respond and for your time, patience and expertise.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';


CREATE TABLE encryption_values
(
  NAME   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  VALUE  NVARCHAR2(100)
);

​
INSERT INTO encryption_values
   SELECT 'key' NAME,
          RAWTOHEX ('52AB32;^$!ER94988OPS3W21') VALUE
     FROM DUAL
   UNION
   SELECT 'iv' NAME, RAWTOHEX ('TY54ABCX') VALUE FROM DUAL;
/



CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION encrypt_clob (p_clob IN CLOB) return CLOB is
l_clob CLOB;
lb_variable BLOB;
v_key RAW (320);
v_encryption_type PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.AES_CBC_PKCS5; 
v_iv RAW (320);
l_dest_offset  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
l_src_offset   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
l_lang_context PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
l_warning      PLS_INTEGER;
l_step PLS_INTEGER := 1998;
begin
    SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_key
     FROM encryption_values
     WHERE name = 'key';
  
 SELECT VALUE
    INTO v_iv
     FROM encryption_values
    WHERE name = 'iv';

dbms_lob.createtemporary(lb_variable, true);

DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT(
                 dst => lb_variable,
                 src => p_clob,
                 typ => v_encryption_type,
                 key => v_key,
                 iv => v_iv
                 );

  DBMS_LOB.createTemporary(
    lob_loc => l_clob,
    cache   => TRUE);


  FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(lb_variable) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
        l_clob := l_clob || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(lb_variable, l_step, i * l_step + 1)));
      END LOOP;
   RETURN l_clob;

end encrypt_clob;
/

CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION decrypt_clob (p_clob IN CLOB) return CLOB is 
  lb_variable CLOB; 
  l_clob CLOB;
  l_blob BLOB;
  v_key RAW (320);
  v_encryption_type PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.AES_CBC_PKCS5;
  v_iv RAW (320);
  l_dest_offset  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_src_offset   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  l_lang_context PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
  l_warning      PLS_INTEGER;

  l_raw     RAW(32767);
  l_amt     NUMBER := 16;

  l_offset  NUMBER := 1;
  l_temp    VARCHAR2(32767);
 
begin 
    SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_key
     FROM encryption_values
    WHERE name = 'key';
  
 SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_iv
     FROM encryption_values
    WHERE name = 'iv';
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_blob, true);

-- base-64 string has line breaks; those could give an inaccurate result to the decode function below, so they are replaced with NULL.

l_clob := replace(replace(p_clob, chr(13), null), chr(10), null);


   FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_clob) - 1 )/l_amt) LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.read(l_clob, l_amt, l_offset, l_temp);
      l_offset := l_offset + l_amt;
      l_raw    := UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_temp));
      DBMS_LOB.append (l_blob, TO_BLOB(l_raw));
    END LOOP; 

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(lb_variable, true);

 DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT( 
                 dst => lb_variable, 
                 src => l_blob, 
                 typ => v_encryption_type,--dbms_crypto.des_cbc_pkcs5, 
                 key => v_key,
                 iv => v_iv
                 ); 

   return lb_variable; 
end decrypt_clob;
/

CREATE table t(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
hash_pk VARCHAR2(1000) not NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
c CLOB,
encrypted VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N',
create_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);
/

CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION HASH_SHA512 (
    psINPUT IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    rHash RAW (512);
    BEGIN
    rHash := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH (TO_CLOB (psINPUT), 
dbms_crypto.HASH_SH512);
    RETURN (LOWER (RAWTOHEX (rHash)));
    END HASH_SHA512;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_clob(
 p_clob IN CLOB,
 p_encrypted VARCHAR2
) AS 
  l_hash_pk VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN

SELECT HASH_SHA512(p_clob) INTO l_hash_pk from dual;

IF (p_encrypted = 'N')
THEN

insert into t (hash_pk, c, encrypted) 
    
select l_hash_pk, p_clob, p_encrypted from dual

where not exists(select 1 
                 from t 
                 where (hash_pk = l_hash_pk));

ELSE 

insert into t (hash_pk, c, encrypted) 

select l_hash_pk, encrypt_clob (p_clob), p_encrypted from dual
where not exists(select 1 
                 from t 
                 where (hash_pk = l_hash_pk));


END IF;

END;


declare
  c1 clob := empty_clob();
  c2 varchar2(32000);

BEGIN 

for i in 1 .. 3
 loop
 c2 := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' || i;

dbms_output.put_line(c2);
      
SELECT CONCAT(c1, c2) INTO c1 FROM DUAL;
 insert_clob (c1, 'Y');

 c1 := empty_clob();
 c2 := NULL;
 end loop;
END;


UPDATE t 
set c = decrypt_clob(c),encrypted = 'N' where encrypted ='Y';


-- As you can see from the dump() the decrypted CLOB doesn't match the original CLOB.

SELECT  c, dump(to_char(c)) from t;
/

C    DUMP(TO_CHAR(C))
abcdefgh0QKEmnopqrstuvwxyz 1    Typ=1 Len=28: 97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,48,81,75,69,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,32,49
abcdefgh�klmnopqrstuvwxyz 2    Typ=1 Len=30: 97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,239,191,189,22,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,32,50
abcdefgh�klmnopqrstuvwxyz 3    Typ=1 Len=30: 97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,239,191,189,22,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,32,51
```